# Sprites are colliding, but the ball won't bounce in opposite direction

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

Here is my collision detection code (skim it if necessary):

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(my_ball, ballGroup, False):
    Ball.speed[1] = -Ball.speed[1]
    print '1'
Ball.move()

if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(dad, ballGroup, False):
    Ball.speed[1] = -Ball.speed[1]
Ball.move()
```

The program is telling me two sprites are colliding (`print '1'`in code), so the ball in this code (called `Ball`) should be "bouncing" off the other sprite in the opposite direction. But it is just passing through the sprite, not bouncing. Why is this happening?

Comment: It's a bit confusing. You've got a class called `Ball` and then you define `Ball` as an instance of `Puck`. The `Ball` and `myBall` classes also appear identical. I'd add some more debugging, e.g. print `Ball.speed` at collision but before and after you change it.

Comment: That is because both classes are for the first player's hockey paddle and the second player's hockey paddle. They are to be the same for a fair game.

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly my point: if they are identical then you can just create your `my_ball` and `Dad` objects using the same `Ball` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the script so the image just moves horizontally then your puck has no vertical velocity. This means that the line:

```
Ball.speed[1] = -Ball.speed[1]
```

does nothing.

If you change it to

```
Ball.speed[0] = -Ball.speed[0]
```

then that should reverse the horizontal velocity.

Separately, your `Ball.move()` line will run twice for each loop...